# Value in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a function in Excel that finds the last value in the row and copies the information to a different cell.
i.e last info is on cell row 2 column AX = 'hello', then to copy it to row 2 column F.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to write a function in Excel you will not be using vb.net.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
Do you know how I can do it?
I will also clarify,
i.e. row 2 ends at column F and row 3 ends at column G.
I would like to have on column A the information from the last active cell on each row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score -1):

This is as simple as selecting your desired cell (F2) and typing =AX2 in the formula bar.
If 'hello' is written in AX2, it will be automatically copied to F2.
I suppose if you wanted to employ a user control and VBA to accomplish this, this code would work.

```
Dim str as String
str = Range("AX2")
Range("F2") = str
```

Or even simpler

```
Range("F2") = Range("AX2")
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you very much, 
as I see it doesn't check what is the last active cell only copies AX2
I will try to clarify,
i.e. row 2 ends at column F and row 3 ends at column G.
I would like to have on column A the information from the last active cell on each row.